# Is there a reason for why AccessibilityManager.sInstance would cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, leakcanary

I have an activity that contains a fragment. Running Leak Canary, I see that the activity has a memory leak.

I have commented out all the code from activity and fragment to where the activity is only displaying the fragment and the fragment has an empty xml layout. I have no accessibility in either file or within the xml.

```
* AccessibilityManager$1.!(this$0)! (anonymous subclass of android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityManagerClient$Stub)
* ↳ AccessibilityManager.!(mTouchExplorationStateChangeListeners)!
* ↳ CopyOnWriteArrayList.!(elements)!
* ↳ array Object[].!([2])!
* ↳ AccessibilityManagerCompat$TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerWrapper.!(mListener)!
* ↳ BaseTransientBottomBar$SnackbarBaseLayout$1.!(this$0)! (anonymous implementation of android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat$TouchExplorationStateChangeListener)
* ↳ Snackbar$SnackbarLayout.mContext
* ↳ ContextThemeWrapper.mBase
* ↳ MessagesActivity
```

Comment: Do you have Instant Run enabled? https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#instant-run-can-trigger-invalid-leaks Otherwise, this may be a problem somewhere other than your code: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#can-a-leak-be-caused-by-the-android-sdk

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I will try disabling it. Thank you.

Comment: @CommonsWare disabled Instant run and leak still remained.

Comment: I am having the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I actually got it figured out. This is a memory leak in Snackbar and here is how it can be reproduced: https://github.com/GC-Xi/SnackbarBug

**Way to reproduce**

1. Create a Snackbar and reference it in an Activity
2. Don't call Snackbar.show()
3. Open and close the Activity
4. Notice that the Activity is not garbage collected because snackbar has a reference to it

**Cause**

The `SnackbarBaseLayout` calls `addTouchExplorationStateChangeListener()` in constructor and `removeTouchExplorationStateChangeListener()` in `onDetachedFromWindow()`. Where the `addTouchExplorationStateChangeListener()` probably should be called from `onAttachedToWindow()` because the `SnackbarBaseLayout` is not attached to window unless `Snackbar.show()` is called.

**Solution 1**

Update to AndroidX and use com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar instead.
https://github.com/GC-Xi/SnackbarBug/tree/solution1

**Solution 2**

Do not create the Snackbar unless you are ready to show it.
https://github.com/GC-Xi/SnackbarBug/tree/solution2

Comment: @AndroidLearner No problem. Please accept my answer if this works for you.

Comment: Haven't fully finished testing it yet but I will once I do so tomorrow. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: "Do not create the Snackbar unless you are ready to show it." Excellent advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced similar problem. I was holding a reference to a Snackbar. After I removed that reference, this memory leak went away.

**Update**

For example, replace

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Hello Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
snackbar.show()
```

with

```
Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Hello Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show()
```

I don't know why it fixed my problem. I was not able to reproduce this memory leak in other projects. Based on the stack trace, it seems like  `BaseTransientBottomBar.onDetachedFromWindow()` is not being called by the system, so `touchExplorationStateChangeListener` is not removed from `accessibilityManager`. Again, I don't know why this happened. Below is the code for `BaseTransientBottomBar.onDetachedFromWindow()`.

```
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (this.onAttachStateChangeListener != null) {
            this.onAttachStateChangeListener.onViewDetachedFromWindow(this);
        }

        AccessibilityManagerCompat.removeTouchExplorationStateChangeListener(this.accessibilityManager, this.touchExplorationStateChangeListener);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post example code about how this happening?